# T-SQL CASE WHEN BETWEEN not recognising condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, dateadd, date-comparison

I have a query that is trying to determine whether dates in a table are currently between now and into a day in the future, for a certain ID.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE
            WHEN MyDate >= GETDATE() AND MyDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()) 
               THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END) AS DatesNearlyOverdue
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyId = 1;
```

My issue is that the `WHEN` condition seems to be ignored, and will return the same results as `WHEN TaskDateDue < GETDATE() THEN 1`, for example. I have also tried conditions using `DATEDIFF` and `BETWEEN` but the results are always the same.

What is causing all of these conditions to return the same results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `COUNT`, which is just as happy to count `0`s as `1`s. If you want your `ELSE` values ignored by `COUNT`, use `NULL` rather than `0`:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(
        CASE
            WHEN MyDate >= GETDATE() AND MyDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()) THEN 1
            ELSE NULL -- <== Change is here
            END) AS DatesNearlyOverdue
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyId = 1;
```

Having said that, the more straightforward version of that query would be:

```
SELECT  COUNT(1) AS DatesNearlyOverdue
FROM    MyTable
WHERE   MyId = 1
AND     MyDate >= GETDATE()
AND     MyDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE());
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my simple oversight, the revision of my query is very welcome too.

Answer (score 1):

If you **really want** to use `THEN 1 ELSE 0` branches, because it makes your code easier to read, you are actually looking for `SUM()`:

```
SELECT
    SUM (
        CASE
            WHEN MyDate >= GETDATE() AND MyDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()) 
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS DatesNearlyOverdue
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyId = 1;
```